# How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

I have a rooted Samsung S4 mini with the latest stable CyanogenMod installed (cm-10.2.1.3).

I was playing with the Google Device Manager (https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and tried to lock the device.

When I tried to unlock I found out, **there is no keyboard or input box to enter the password into**.

The screen looks exactly the same as my lockscreen - I'm using the pattern lock which I remmember perfectly - besides there are just words: "locked" and the message I typed into the web remote lock. I can also see there is Android Device Manager running in background (icon in top left notification corner). Wherever I click or try to draw my pattern lock, the device does nothing (but it is not frozen as I can open the Power button menu).

I also use a custom keyboard application and I removed the original CyanogenMod keyboard. Can this be a problem?

1. Is there any option at the online Device Manager to remotely unlock
   the device?
2. The phone is rooted and I can connect via ADB in Recovery. Can I do something there - besides wiping
   the device - to unlock the remote lock?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve the problem by clicking the "Emergency Call" button.

That enforced the keyboard to come up and after closing the Emergency Call screen there was a window to enter Google Device Manager password.

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type:

```
adb shell
```

Now enter these commands:

```
su
rm /data/system/cm_gesture.key
reboot
```

If a lockscreen appears after reboot, it should accept any pattern.

Comment: This may help when you forget your lockscreen password. But won't help for Google Device Manager remote lock.