# Google Device Manager on CyanogenMod - How to stop asking me to unlock phone all the time?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, android-device-manager

I was playing around with [Google Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and so I decided to lock my phone to see it working.

Now every time I have to use my phone I have to unlock it with the password and after a while. It is annoying.

How can I stop it asking me for the password every time I turn ON the screen?

I'm using CyanogenMod 11 (Android 4.4.4) on a Galaxy S4

PS; I've read [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68687/how-to-unlock-google-device-manager-remote-lock) question here on SE but not exactly the same problem as me. I can input the password and unlock it. I want to make it stop asking me to unlock the phone all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to solve this.

```
1- Unlock the phone (as usual) 
2- Go to settings 
3- Go to Device
4 Go to lock screen 
5 Select none 
6 Press back 
7 Turn off your screen, wait 5 seconds, and turn on again and you should have no lock at all.
8- Problem solved.
```

If you want to add a "normal" lock screen again, repeat steps 2, 3 and 4 and select your lock screen.