# Applied Pin Lock screen to Galaxy S6 Edge, forgot password, need to get photos from phone

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, android-device-manager, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have tried using Google android device manager and end up with

"Since Google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the password you entered won't be needed."

Samsung's find my mobile site will not work because I didn't register device prior to being locked out.

I am desperate to get the photos and videos from the phone. They are memories I want to keep, please help.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! You might wish to take a look at our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) – and [other questions with answers for the same issue](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+device+manager+lock+answers%3A1), especially: [How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/68687/16575)

Answer (score -1):

You can use your Google account to unlock the phone.

Here's the steps from Google:

1. After you've tried multiple times to unlock your device, you'll see "Forgot pattern" on your lock screen. Touch Forgot pattern.
2. When prompted, enter the Google Account username and password you previously added to your device.
3. Reset your device's screen lock.