# Forgot Pattern/ Android Device manager not prompting keyboard

Tags: android-device-manager

I have forgot my pattern and locked the my sony z3 compact using the Android Device Manager. Unfortunately when the screens prompts the "Locked by Android Device Manager" i have no option to enter the code. There is no keyboard popping up or anything. I just have a black screen with the above message.

Does anyone know how can i input the password?

Comment: If USB debugging is enabled, you can do `adb input text <PASSWORD>`

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/69321/16575) helps you out?

Answer (score 0):

Press the home button or back button. The soft keyboard will pop up.