# Forgot screen lock PIN on Samsung Galaxy Note 4

Tags: locked-out, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Logged in to device manager using gmail account. Over internet locked the phone and reset the password. Received the message on the phone that it is locked using android device manager. But when I try unlocking the screen using new pin it says 'wrong pin'. I do not want to loose data by resetting to factory setting. Can anyone help please.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Starting point: our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). Especially take a look at: [How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/68687/16575) and [similar questions with answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+device+manager+lock+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 1):

Follow this simple steps to [unlock forgotten password/pattern lock on android](http://www.indabaa.com/how-to-unlock-forgotten-pattern-lock-on-android-phones/)

It is mostly seen that when you type wrong password few times, your phone will give you message “Try Again in 30 Seconds”. Apart from this it will also gives you an option: Forgot Password or Pattern.

Step #1: Tap on this option.

Step #2: When you click on Forgot Password option, you will get two options: Unlock with security question OR Unlock with Google account.

Step #3: Tap on Google account option.

Step #4: Login with Google account to get connected.

Step #5: Now you can select a new pattern or type in a new password.

Step #6: Type new password and access your android device easily without losing any data.

**Disclosure**: I'm the author of the linked article.