# Cant unlock phone after using Google's Find my Device

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

I forgot my phone's pattern lock, when I used Google's Find my Device, it just locks my phone and I don't know what to do. How can I get back in to my phone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how new your phone is, but some of the older builds allow you to do a factory data reset, and it clears off the password. If you were lucky and had USB debugging enabled at the time of locking it up, you could do a backup of your stuff to your computer before you do the factory reset. I use Mobogenie, although some people say it's buggy, and it does have a lot of adware. I'm fairly sure you should be able to use Mobogenie on it even if the device is locked.
By the way, as far as i know, Google's Find My Device is for only if it's lost or stolen and you want to find it, or lock it up so a thief can't access it.
EDIT: To unlock your phone via ADB without factory reset(if you had USB debugging enabled), read this answer to another post [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/68692/229049).