# Locked out of my device,

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

I used google find my device to locked my stolen Samsung galaxy j7 Prime. Its been recovered, but i can't unlock it because apparently, the password input bar wont take more than certain number of characters. What can i do please

Comment: you can set a temporary password from google find my device and unlock then

Comment: I already did that, no difference

Comment: what do you mean with "wont take more than certain number"? Why not use a shorter temporary password which fits in "certain number"?

Comment: Have you seen [How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/68687/16575)